# Android EditText Layout Width Full size

Tags: android, user-interface, android-manifest

I am new to Android and i am creating a test app for learning and in this i want my Edit-text field width to be as wide as the Device is i.e EditText field should filled 100% of width as long as the Device width .

I tried everything but didn't succeed.Any Clue What can i do here?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:onClick="doDis"
    android:text="@string/aarti_collection" />
```

Comment: Instead of wrap_content have `android:layout_width="match_parent` for linear layout"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:onClick="doDis"
    android:text="@string/aarti_collection" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
// since you have wrap_content  it will not take the full width
```

By

```
android:layout_width="match_parent
```

for LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

All the best for your developemnt.

Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

fill_parent (deprecated and renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher)

Setting the layout of a widget to fill_parent will force it to expand to take up as much space as is available within the layout element it's been placed in. It's roughly equivalent of setting the dockstyle of a Windows Form Control to Fill.

Setting a top level layout or control to fill_parent will force it to take up the whole screen.

wrap_content

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains. For controls -- like text boxes (TextView) or images (ImageView) -- this will wrap the text or image being shown. For layout elements it will resize the layout to fit the controls / layouts added as its children.

It's roughly the equivalent of setting a Windows Form Control's Autosize property to True.